# using Python's subprocess for reading the output of a blocking command sent through stdin

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, stdin, popen

I have the following code:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["adb", "shell"], stdout.subprocess.PIPE, subprocess.PIPE)
proc.stdin.write("cat /proc/kmsg")
```

The command keeps outputting data to the stdout, and I'm interested in stopping the command (CTRL-C) at a certain time, and reading the whole outputted data.
Right now the only thing I'm able to do is **proc.stdout.readline()** and hoping the next line is not empty.
I'm interested in stopping the command and reading whatever lines I have consumed up until this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `proc.kill()` then `proc.communicate()` to finish reading.

Comment: You're welcome.  Please consider clicking the checkmark on the left of this answer to "accept" it.  Welcome to SO.